# Migrating Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL: Odd errors I can't find documentation or fixes for, including "text is too long"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, database-migration

I have a database in SQL Server that I am trying to convert into a MySQL database, so I can host it on AWS and move everything off-premises. From [this link](https://www.silicongadget.com/software/database/import-mssql-bak-files-to-mysql/2955/), it seems like normally this is no big deal, although that link doesn't seem to migrate from a .bak file so much as from your local instance of SQL Server that is running and contains the database in question. No big deal, I can work with that.

However when I actually use MySQL Workbench to migrate using these steps, it gets to the Bulk Data Transfer step, and then comes up with odd errors.

[image]

I get errors like the following:

> ERROR: `OptionalyticsCoreDB-Prod`.`UserTokens`:Inserting Data: Data too long for column 'token' at row 1

> ERROR: `OptionalyticsCoreDB-Prod`.`UserTokens`:Failed copying 6 rows

> ERROR: `OptionalyticsCoreDB-Prod`.`UserLogs`:Inserting Data: Data too long for column 'ActionTaken' at row 1
> ERROR: `OptionalyticsCoreDB-Prod`.`UserLogs`:Failed copying 244 rows

However the data should not be "too long." These columns are nvarchar(MAX) in SQL Server, and the data for them is often very short in the specified rows, nothing that approaches the maximum value for an nvarchar.

[Links like this](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66516) and [this](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67289) show that there used to be, almost a decade ago, bugs with nvarchar formats, but they've been fixed for years now. I have checked and even updated and restarted my software and then computer - I have up-to-date versions of MySQL and MySQL Workbench. So what's going on?

What is the problem here, and how do I get my database successfully migrated? Surely it's *possible* to migrate from SQL Server to MySQL, right?

Comment: You said they are `nvarchar(max)` in SQL Server. What size are they in MySQL?

Comment: @HardCode I'm migrating the database including table design, I think I read lastnight when googling like crazy that nvarchar(MAX) should become longtext in MYSQL (which has a capacity larger than nvarchar(MAX), so anything in those columns should be easily transferrable, no?)

Answer (score 1):

I have answered my own question... Apparently there IS some sort of bug with Workbench when translating SQL Server nvarchar(MAX) columns. I output the schema migration to a script and examined it, it was translating those columns as varchar(0). After replacing all of them with TEXT columns, the completed migration worked.

Frustrating lesson.